# Bitwise operator with large numbers

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to check greater values then "2147483648"?
I have to work with numbers up to "6.73297395398192e212" (2^707).
The data is stored in a mysql-database as float.

Maybe I'm just using the wrong search terms or there is not a good way.

Comment: In the usual way?  `WHERE field > 2147483648`

Comment: no such as
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 4;
$d = 8;
$e = 16;
$f = 32;

// 32, 16, 4 are set and will be echo'd
if (52 & 1) echo "1 is set";
if (52 & 2) echo "2 is set";
if (52 & 4) echo "4 is set";
if (52 & 8) echo "8 is set";
if (52 & 16) echo "16 is set";
if (52 & 32) echo "32 is set";

Comment: I don't understand what you just said.  What does all that have to do with checking the range of a number?

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're trying to do, not with a floating point number anyway.  Floating point numbers don't have the same bit-wise representation as integers; they're broken into two parts: the mantissa and the exponent, neither of which has the bit-precision that you require.  What you're probably looking for is a `bigint` field; see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html

Comment: @datCake What are you trying to do? What is your problem you try to solve with bitwise operators on such large numbers?

Answer (score 1):

[A double precision value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) uses 8 bytes, and you obviously cannot store 707 bits in those (which I assume you are trying to do). It can store a value of 1e308 by an [approximation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html) that costs precision in the lower digits, which makes it a bad choice for storing data that you want to do bitwise operations on. For bitwise operation on 8 bytes, you can use bigint.

Since MySQL 8, MySQL supports [bitwise operations on binary string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html) of arbitrary length, so you should store your value that way - a bit array is basically a binary string anyway. You cannot treat them as numbers though (e.g. add or multiply them like integers).

For earlier MySQL versions, bit operations on binary strings were limited to 8 bytes. You should still store your bits as a binary string (which allows for an easy upgrade), and write a small function that does the operation e.g. bytewise.